# Component Analysis in the Subcritical Hypergraph

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory, reference-request, random-graphs

Let $H_k(n,p)$ be the random $k$-uniform hypergraph on $n$ vertices, where each hyperedge $E\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$, $|E|=k$, is included independently with probability $p$. Further, let $d=\binom{n-1}{k-1}p$ be the average vertex degree. For a long time, we know (e.g. from [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579445) or [here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eaf1p/BOOK.pdf)) that a large component emerges at $\alpha=\frac{1}{k-1}$, meaning that for $\alpha\in(0,\frac{1}{k-1})$ and $p=\alpha/\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ the size of the largest component is $\mathcal O(\ln(n))$, while for $\alpha>\frac{1}{k-1}$ it is $\Theta(n)$.
For $\alpha<\frac{1}{k-1}$ the hypergraph is subcritical, and supercritical for $\alpha>\frac{1}{k-1}$.

For graphs, i.e. the special case $k=2$, we have a thorough understanding of the subcritical (and supercritical) regime, as discussed [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/random-graphs/E21023008001CFA182CE666F5028489F), [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118032718), [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-random-graphs/0F67A19795B731B0C97EAB5BB5748CF2) and in countless other books.
In particular, say Corollary 5.8 in [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/random-graphs/E21023008001CFA182CE666F5028489F) book, we know that in the subcritical regime all connected components are trees or unicyclic, and the number of unicyclic components is at most $f(n)$ for any $f(n)=\omega(1)$, with probability tending to $1$.

Now, we turn to hypergraphs. A connected hypergraph on $n$ vertices with $m$ hyperdges is a hypertree if $n=(k-1)m+1$ (isolated vertices are hypertrees), and unicyclic if $n=(k-1)m$.

**Questions**

- Does Corollary 5.8 hold for all $k\ge 2$, i.e. is it true that for $\alpha<\frac{1}{k-1}$ all connected components are trees or unicyclic, and the number of unicyclic components is at most $f(n)$ for any $f(n)=\omega(1)$, with probability tending to $1$?
- If not, does there exist such a characterization of the subcritical regime for $k>2$?
- Does there exist any book on random (binomial or uniform) hypergraphs covering the standard results?

The only related result I found so far is in Section 9.4.1 in the [blue book](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Emontanar/RESEARCH/BOOK/partC.pdf) (for the uniform model on labeled hyperedges), where it's established that the expected *ratio* of vertices covered by *finite size* trees approaches $1$, which suggests that the ratio of vertices covered by trees approaches $1$, with probability tending to $1$.

Comment: Question 3 is also something I'm looking for...

Comment: I asked around at my uni & it seems that no such book exists. I got the task to write it :D If it helps, the book by Frieze and Karonski at least has a dedicated section: https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/BOOK.pdf